# Избавиться от повторений с++

Tags: c++

Как избавиться от повторения значений?

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        const int n = 100;
        char *Empty[100];
        char *Empty2[100];
        char *Names[] = { "Alexandr", "Kostya", "Roman" };
        char *Work[] = { "Stoloter", "Posudomoyka", "Shef" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

                Empty[i] = Names[rand() % 3];
                cout << Empty[i] << " ";
                Empty2[i] = Work[rand() % 3];
                cout << Empty2[i] << "\n";

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Нужно выбрать 3 пары, но что бы при этом не было повторения Имен и Профессий.

Comment: От повторений чего??? Вы хотите случайно выбрать 3 раза пару "Имя - Профессия"?

Comment: Да, выбрать 3 пары, но что бы при этом не было повторения Имен и Профессий.

Comment: Кто такой **столотер**?

Comment: Столотер - человек который моет стол; употреблять строго на территории общаги.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое что пришло в голову записовать значения функции rand() в массив и при следующем ее вызове проверять есть ли такое значение в массиве. Если есть опять вызывать ренд пока она не сгенерит не повторяющегося значения( но этот варик пригоден если у вас там массиы Names и Work относительно не большие. А вообще раз это С++,а не С там есть STL, в ней свой рендом, а в нем куча распределений.

Comment: Не могли бы подсказать как реализовать это?

Answer (score 4):

Если я верно понимаю, что вы хотите - то проще всего сделать два массива с индексами и случайным образом их переставить.

```
int idx1[3] = {0,1,2};
int idx2[3] = {0,1,2};
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    int j = rand()%(3-i)+i;
    // Можно использовать функцию swap, если знаете такую...
    int tmp = idx1[i]; idx1[i] = idx1[j]; idx1[j] = tmp;
    j = rand()%(3-i)+i;
    tmp = idx2[i]; idx2[i] = idx2[j]; idx2[j] = tmp;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

    Empty[i] = Names[idx1[i]];
    cout << Empty[i] << " ";
    Empty2[i] = Work[idx2[i]];
    cout << Empty2[i] << "\n";

}
return 0;
```

Comment: Может быть проблема: вдруг придется не 3 пары, а больше (здесь возможно 3х3 = 9 различных пар)

Comment: Метод расширяется на любое количество :)

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы использовать метод с которого начал я.

Comment: Да пожалуйста, решение за вами...

Comment: @Harry а как на любое, на 5, например?)

Comment: @AlexandrT, идея состоит в том, что Вы пробегаете по массиву от первого до *предпоследнего* элемента (`i` -- индекс этого элемента) и используя rand вычисляете индекс (`j`) в диапазоне от `i ` (включительно) до последнего и проводите обмен i-го с j-м элементов. Цикл до предпоследнего, поскольку последний менять уже не с кем. Могу заметить, что это в общем-то известный алгоритм тасования ([shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/))

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, что "профессий", что имён всегда будет одно число. Тогда просто перемешайте каждый массив, а потом выведите их.

Поможет функция [`shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/) (>=C++11) или [`random_shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) (>=C++98) из стандартной библиотеки. В качестве генератора используйте подходящий вам (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/, искать заголовок **Generators**).

[Код](http://cpp.sh/6vyz7):

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::shuffle
#include <array>        // std::array
#include <random>       // std::default_random_engine
#include <chrono>       // std::chrono::system_clock

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    // Help to keep same size
    using Array = array<string, 3>;

    Array names = { "Alexandr", "Kostya",      "Roman" };
    Array work  = { "Stoloter", "Posudomoyka", "Shef"  };

    // obtain a time-based seed:
    unsigned seed = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

    // shuffle both arrays
    shuffle(begin(names), end(names), std::default_random_engine(seed));

    // Update seed and shuffle other array
    seed = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() + 1;
    shuffle(begin(work), end(work), std::default_random_engine(seed));

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < names.size(); ++idx)
    {
        cout << names[idx] << ' ' << work[idx] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Выхлоп на разных запусках может быть таким:

```
$ ./a.out 
Kostya Shef
Roman Stoloter
Alexandr Posudomoyka
$ ./a.out 
Kostya Posudomoyka
Roman Stoloter
Alexandr Shef
$ ./a.out 
Alexandr Stoloter
Kostya Shef
Roman Posudomoyka
```